# PHP concatenation isn't working?

Tags: php

I cannot get my concatenation correct, it simply doesn't work:

Wouldn't this be right?  I'm trying to have the variable inside the select query and echoing the $firstname.

```
<?php $user = $_SESSION["UserID"];?>

<?php
$user = $_SESSION["UserID"]; 

function getFirstname($db) {
    $firstname=false;
    $sql = "SELECT firstname FROM Users WHERE username = '$user'";
    foreach ($db->query($sql) as $row) {
        $firstname=$row['firstname'];
    }
    return $firstname;
}

$firstname=getFirstname( $db );
?>


<?php echo $firstname  ?>
```

It doesn't seem to output the firstname.

Answer (score 2):

You have either pass $user to function or set global $user into the function like this below code
And (.) for concatnaion

```
function getFirstname($db) {
     global $user;
    $firstname=false;
    $sql = "SELECT firstname FROM Users WHERE username = '$user'";
    foreach ($db->query($sql) as $row) {
        $firstname.=$row['firstname'];
    }
    return $firstname;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much. will accept in 8 minutes when it lets me.

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
function getFirstname($db) {
    global $user;
    $firstname=false;
    $sql = "SELECT firstname FROM Users WHERE username = '$user'";
    foreach ($db->query($sql) as $row) {
        $firstname .= $row['firstname'];
    }
    return $firstname;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try This

```
<?php $user = $_SESSION["UserID"];?>
<?php
$user = $_SESSION["UserID"]; 

function getFirstname($db) {
    $firstname=false;
    global $user;
    $sql = "SELECT `firstname` FROM `Users` WHERE `username` = '{$user}'";
    foreach ($db->query($sql) as $row) {
        $firstname=$row['firstname'];
    }
    return $firstname;
}

$firstname=getFirstname( $db );
?>

<?php echo $firstname  ?>
```